# Error in ngModel when strictTemplates is true in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have one project in Angular 12 which is giving a problem after the notation `strictTemplates`

In my component I have this property:

```
@Output('ngModelChange') ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

When I remove the property or put in `tscongif.json` `"strictTemplates": false`, the component works.

My reusable component:

```html
<xt-select
  xt-label="test"
  [xt-options]="[
    { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' }
  ]"
  [(ngModel)]="select2"
  >
</xt-select>
```

I would like to know what the problem would be, I would not like to `false` the `strictTemplates` that defaults to angular in true. And because this "output" property is causing this, when "strictTemplates" is set to true.

Error:

`The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'ngModel' are  not bound to the same target.` 
 `node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3297:22 3297 export declare class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy { ~~~~~~~ The property half of the binding is to the 'NgModel' component.`

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @GunnarB. sorry, I updated the question with the error

Comment: From what I've read (by searching for that error), you could try to change the order of `[xt-options]` and `[(ngModel)]`, maybe even move move ngModel to be before `xt-label`. You might also try to change `xt-label="test"` to `[xt-label]="'test'"`.